# Error using simple pandas script

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to run a simple script to sort a dataframe by a column but am getting thrown off by this error.

The following code i'm trying to run:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('pandas_test.xlsx', sheetname='mydata')
print df
df.sort_values(by = 'Prediction', ascending=[False], inplace=True)
```

This is the read out

```
             Name    Code  Prediction   Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4
0           Aiden    ADN     -0.904636   -0.897691   -0.897691
1        ARCHcoin   ARCH      0.058027    0.279917    0.279917
2         ArtByte    ABY      0.083942    0.396728    0.262711
3       BellaCoin   BELA     -0.622574   -0.357308    0.348456
4    Bitcoin Plus    XBC     -0.862629   -0.862629   -0.927854
5     BitcoinDark   BTCD     -0.349041   -0.495764   -0.071606
6         Bitmark    BTM     -0.712551   -0.686572   -0.686910
7       BitShares     BTS     0.658777    0.645338    0.653746
8   BitShares PTS    PTS     -0.009761   -0.599135   -0.404015
9         Bitstar   BITS      0.365824    0.388928    0.541017
10      BlackCoin    BLK     -0.153565   -0.040735    0.348264
11       Blocknet  BLOCK      0.172974    0.403764   -0.011830
12      Boolberry    BBR     -0.556053   -0.570189   -0.441098
13      Boolberry     BBR    -0.556053   -0.570189   -0.441098
14          Burst  BURST     -0.302751   -0.301617   -0.201896
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Python\JSON\pandas_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    df.sort_values(by = 'Prediction', ascending=[False], inplace=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3098, in sort_values
    k = self[by].values
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1969, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1976, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1091, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3211, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1759, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 668, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12265)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 676, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12216)
KeyError: 'Prediction'
[Finished in 1.0s with exit code 1]
```

It's not letting me post as it's saying i have mostly code, even though it's mostly error log, i'm going to babble down here until i have enough text

Comment: tbh, I'm no [panda] expert but if `ascending=[False]` then why is `inplace=True` and not `inplace=[True]`?

Comment: @Jeeped, inplace parameters expects only a bool while ascending and by are allowing a list. There would be an error if both list were not having the same sizes.

Comment: Do you have a space after the Prediction word in your excel ? That would explain the KeyError. And according to the way the print is done it looks like it (last char of the column name should be aligned with the last char of the values)

Comment: Thanks man, this was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Sort_values is depreciated! Use df.sort instead.

```
 df.sort(columns=None, axis=0, ascending=False, 
                    inplace=False,kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
```

Also the inplace argument needs a boolian **False** not a list **[False]**

Comment: 'sort' is now deprecated, we should use 'sort_values'. [Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html?highlight=sort#pandas.DataFrame.sort).